# Converting a pandas dtype string representation to dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I am having problems trying to convert a dtype representation to a dict.
Actually, I am sending this string via an API in order to use it inside a read_csv function:

```
MyString='{"dept": str}' # This is received from an API

pd.read_csv(file, dtype=MyString)
--> data type '{"dept": str}' not understood: TypeError

# Then, I tried: 
pd.read_csv(file, dtype=dict(MyString))
--> ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

# In a desperate move, I did:
pd.read_csv(file, dtype=ast.literal_eval(MyString))
--> ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x7f3527139128>
```

What am I missing and how can I achieve this please? From pandas documentation:

```
dtype : Type name or dict of column -> type, optional
Data type for data or columns
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string contains a class name, so it will not be easy to parse, and cannot be with `literal_eval`, nor with the json module.

I can only imagine 2 ways

1. use the evil `eval`. If you are sure that nothing wrong can come there, you could `eval` the string

   ```
    pd.read_csv(file, dtype=ast.literal_eval(MyString))
   ```

   As it allows execution of arbitrary code, this should only be the desperate way. But at least it immediately works.
2. parse the string, and make `str` a string:

   Provided the string coming from the API contains no misplaced comma, colon or quote character, you could use:

   ```
    dt = {k: v for elt in MyString[1:-1].split(',')
          for k,v in [[i.strip('" ') for i in elt.split(':', 1)]]}
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), dtype=dt)
   ```